# Keep Grid Items The Height Of The Content and Thus Prevent Them Matching Their Parent Height - CSS

Tags: html, css, height, css-grid

I have a grid where one of the two grid items (columns) has its own grid. This inner grid is also two columns and is going to hold blog posts.

I would like it so the articles inside this inner grid don't stretch the full height of the parent container, but effectively stack from the top down and their height is restricted to that of their content (i.e. the text + the given padding). Is this possible to do?

In the example code it would mean the yellow `<article>` elements being stack up at the top of the column and separated by the grid gap still.

Code snippet is below or CodePen is here: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/WNwNayG

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main {
  background: #fff;
  width: 50%;
  height: 90%;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.column {
  background: lightgray;
}

.column-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

/* GRID ITEMS THAT I WANT TO RESTRICT THEIR HEIGHT TO THAT OF THEIR CONTENT */
.article {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="column column-1">
      <article class="article">Lorem Ipsum</article>
      <article class="article">Lorem Ipsum</article>
      <article class="article">Lorem Ipsum</article>
      <article class="article">Lorem Ipsum</article>
    </div>
    <aside class="column column-2"></aside>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: align-items:flex-start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `align-content: start;`

```
.column-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  align-content: start;
}
```